# single validation script for select dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, select, validation

I am creating a user form. In this I have textbox and a lot of number of select dropdown.
After submitting I send all the value to database by $_POST. My form is like This:

```
     <tr>
         <td>Review Employee Id</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="rcode" id="rcode"  class="genInputBox" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Quality of Delivery</td>
         <td>
              <select name="qd" id="qd">
                <option value="">Plz Select Ratting </option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
              </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
```

And more select boxes.........

and for select box validtion I am using like this

```
   var qd = document.product.qd.options[document.product.qd.selectedIndex].value;
       if (qd == "") {
           error_message = error_message + "Please select Rating In domain Knowledge\n";
           error = 1;
       }
```

I mentioned lot of select boxes in the form. So my question is can I use a single select box validation script for all select boxes?

I use this answer In this manner

```
var sels = document.product.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var i=0,n=sels.length;i<n;i++) {
  if (sels[i].selectedIndex<1) {
    alert(sels[i].options[0]); // alerts Plz Select whatever
    sels[i].focus();

  error_message = error_message + "Please select drop down\n";
   error = 1; }
}
   if (error == 1) {
    alert(error_message);
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
```

}

but now if a left only 1 single select drop down without check,then its show 10 error message for selectbox.

Comment: Have you considered using something like jQuery validation? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: no,I want to use javascript not by jquery

Comment: Ok. Then use document.getElementsByTagName('select') and validate them on submit.

Comment: depends on what/how you need the other selects to validate against

Comment: I wanna all validation in same manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this - plain JS -

```
window.onload=function() {
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]; // assuming first form on page
  form.onsubmit=function() {
    var sels = form.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i=0,n=sels.length;i<n;i++) {
      if (sels[i].selectedIndex<1) {
        alert(sels[i].options[0]); // alerts Plz Select whatever
        sels[i].focus();
        return false; // disallow submit
      }
    }
    return true; // allow submission
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude. Nice shot. What is JQuery, anyways? haha  :) 

I am trying to do little things without frameworks and answers like yours make me appreciate the beauty of the language itself, *rather than some frameworks api* (to take nothing away from the power of jquery), it's just nice to see op trying to implement in P-U-R-E js.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, like:

```
var firstSelectLen = document.product.qd.length;
var secondSelectLen = document.product.qd1.length; // and so on for all selects you have
//then loop with lengths to check if any selected
//and show error msg accordingly
```

Hope it helps